# What is the maximum value of a number value before you start losing precision in Power Automate Cloud Flows?

Tags: power-automate

What is the maximum value of a number value before you start losing precision in Power Automate Cloud Flows?

I found this connector documentation that says the SQL bigint is being converted to the number type in Power Automate Cloud Flows.
[power apps data type mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#power-apps-data-type-mappings)

I have a workflow that is rounding '-9223372036854769664' to '-9223372036854775000' when the value is returned by the SQL Server Get Rows (V2) action. The value is rounded again to '-9223372036854770000' when I use the value in the SQL Server Insert Row (V2) action.